# htaccess localization with subdomains and subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

basically I've got a problem in building a robust rewrite rule for a scenario that is explainable via this example:

I've got a website that works on 3 different subdomains:

```
http://www.domain.tld
http://subdom1.domain.tld
http://subdom2.domain.tld
```

Now, I've been requested to add localization functionalities. The main language is IT, the EN language should be added.
What i want to achieve is an url structure like this:

```
http://www.domain.tld   => maps to IT homepage
http://www.domain.tld/en/    => maps to EN homepage
http://subdom1.domain.tld/en    => maps to EN homepage of subdom1
```

Or, talking a bit more technically, I want to achieve this url structure:

```
http://(whatever).domain.tld/whatever.*   => maps to the IT representation
http://(whatever).domain.tld/en/whatever.*  => maps to the EN representation
```

Every page on the website passes through a unique page builder, so I would not like to touch the other 160 lines of htaccess to map the /en/ representation of each page.

A very good option I've come to see in stackoverflow, is to use ENV variables, and after a litle bit of copy/paste/mod I've created this piece of rewritecond, but unfortunately it is not working, it reports a 404 not found error for each page called:

```
# if an url matches the /en/whatever, the ENV LANGUAGE gets set to EN
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^en/(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]
# if no ENV variable is present yet, let's default it to IT
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:it]
# rewrite whatever url with the ENV variable posted via GET
RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]
```

Now, I feel like the problem is the last RewriteRule, I guess that it is not enough to make the trick work.
Any suggestions or corrections to the htaccess posted?

Answer (score 0):

After some time, having noticed that handling this type of localization via htaccess would require too much time to rebuild and revamp the IT htaccess rules, I've opted for an htaccess / php hybrid technique.
Every language that will be added to the website will have its own subdirectory, for example "en" for english localization and "fr" for french

```
http://www.domain.tld        => maps to IT homepage
http://www.domain.tld/en/    => maps to EN homepage
http://www.domain.tld/fr/    => maps to FR homepage
```

What I've done is to create a PHYSICAL folder on the root of the IT website, where all the htaccess rules are present, and create an "url preparser" in that folder: every request made to the /en/ or /fr/ localization realms will pass through a php file ( each for every localized language ) that will:

1. Understand what url has been called, what "module" ( cart, search page, and so on )
2. Reparse and 301 redirect if a subdomain mismatches occurr
3. Create the functional variables that a "normal" htaccess would pass to the page builder
4. Include the page builder of the IT website, defining that we are in a localized realm ( en, fr, etc )

This way, there will always be a singular page builder that will work for every page of the website, and it will handle localization only if localization variables have been defined